# Mostrar imágenes que tienen un espacio en su nombre la base de datos

Tags: php, html, web

Estoy haciendo pruebas de subir imágenes a un servidor y luego guardar el link en una base de datos. Las imágenes se guardan con el nombre que tenían al momento de subirlas por lo que algunas tienen nombres en sus espacios y esas imágenes no se muestran después por más que el directorio sea el correcto. Con las imágenes que no tienen un espacio no ocurre ningún problema. Lo que me resulta extraño es que en modo local con XAMPP no tengo ningún problema con el nombre de las imágenes y se muestran ya sea que tengan una sola palabra en el nombre o más.

Este es el código que utilizo para mostrar la imagen:

```
    $result = $connexion->query(
        "SELECT * FROM MUEBLES WHERE TIPO='$categoria' ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT ".$start.", ".NUM_ITEMS_BY_PAGE
    );
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $nombre = $row['NOMBRE'];
             $imagen=$row['IMAGEN'];
             $codigo=$row['CODIGO'];
            echo '<div class="gallery_grid1">
                    <a href="images/'.$imagen.'"><img src="images/'.$imagen.'" alt="'.$nombre.'" / height=160></a>
                    <h4>'.$nombre.'</h4>
                    <h4>'.$codigo.'</h4>
                </div>';
        }
    }
```

No me da ningún problema en modo local o con imágenes con un nombre sencillo, pero no me deja ver las que tienen un nombre compuesto. Sé que una solución sería cambiar el nombre de la imagen antes de subirla, pero el problema es que no siempre el usuario final se va a dar el tiempo de cambiar el nombre y ya tengo un registro de más de 180 productos que sigue creciendo por lo que sería muy tardado cambiar el nombre de cada imagen una por una y luego cambiar su nombre en la base de datos.

Comment: reemplaza los espacios por _ al subirla y se acaban rapidamente tus problemas.. y para lo otro un simple script en la db y en el sistema operativo te deja sin problemas mayores.. no se respecto a tu problema en particular

Comment: La solución sugerida por @gbianchi es la óptima, pero mientras tanto, podrías probar con `$imagen=urlencode($row['IMAGEN'])` para que espacios y caracteres especiales sean codificados para poder usarse en URL

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos, ambas respuestas me fueron útiles. Sobre todo la de Triby que me sacó del apuro mientras mejoro el código para no tener más problemas a futuro. La elegiría como la respuesta aceptada pero no veo la opción para hacerlo. Muchas gracias de nuevo a ambos.